# Working with large numbers(millions) in python dataframe using pyodbc libraries

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

When I'm using Pyodbc library to connect SQL Server I have some trouble with large numbers (millions).

I have a table-valued function like that.(**In this problem I focused on STOCK_AMOUNT column**)

[image]

I am using below code to use the results from the database as dataframe.

```
 stock_info = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.my_func('35214')", con_engine)
```

Here is my situation. I want to some manipulation(math operation) on STOCK_AMOUNT column in stock_info dataframe. But the million numbers seem to be in the thousands.(**Means 7.226M(in db side) --> 7.23K(in python side)**)

### Heading

| STOCK_CODE | STOCK_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 13251 | 7226.516000000001 |
| 10001 | 4020.919999999999 |

You can see the dataframe datatypes below.

[image]

At first I thought it was a data type issue and try to convert STOCK_AMOUNT datatype float64 to float128. (I am using Windows OS, it seem not possible)

**Where am I doing wrong? Is it because of something different from the datatype?
How should this problem be approached?**

Comment: That's exactly what your data says: "7 comma 226 dot 516".  It's not an integer.  If it's supposed to be millions, then they should both be commas.  Is that a string field?  Where are the commas and dots coming from?

Comment: @TimRoberts but when i checked on database stock_amount column seems float type.

Comment: In that case, the value must be 7 thousand 226 point 516.  That's exactly what your image shows.  Perhaps the column was entered incorrectly, but that's what is stored there now.

Comment: Without context, we can't tell if ALL or just a select few numbers where stored in thousands.

Comment: @TimRoberts re: "Where are the commas and dots coming from?" - The screenshot reveals that OP is using DBeaver, which by default (at least for an "en - English" locale) uses digit grouping, so that's where the comma is coming from.